# Merge two array to create an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, associative-array

I have a `php` array something like this:

```
array:7 [▼
  "id" => 13
  "agent_id" => 1
  "reserved_by" => 1
  "vehicle_type" => "["Bus","Car"]"
  "no_of_vehicle" => "["2","1"]"
  "created_at" => "2017-06-13 05:46:49"
  "updated_at" => "2017-06-13 05:46:49"
]
```

Here, `vehicle_type` and `no_of_vehicle` are in `json_encode` format. In the above case,

By `json_decode` I can get two arrays like this

**vehicle_type**

```
dd(json_decode($data->vehicle_type));

array:2 [▼
  0 => "Bus"
  1 => "Car"
]
```

**no_of_vehicle**

```
dd(json_decode($data->no_of_vehicle));

array:2 [▼
  0 => "2"
  1 => "1"
]
```

Now, what I want is to create an associative array of vehicle type and number equals 1.

```
array:3 [▼
  Bus => "1"
  Bus => "1"
  Car => "1"
]
```

It's impossible as all you say because of unique key. But, Is to possible to make similar array with nested like:

```
array:3 [▼
    array:1 [▼
      Bus => "1"
    ]

    array:1 [▼
      Bus => "1"
    ]

    array:1 [▼
      Bus => "1"
    ]
]
```

That will be fine for me
Any idea, I am using `laravel 5.3`

Thanks

Comment: you wont be able to get your desired array as keys are unique. Why not `[Bus=>2,Car=>1]` which makes more sense.

Comment: I have forgot that, Is there any other way to achieve this

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Is to possible to make similar array with nested  like: 
`[[Bus=>1],[Bus=>1],[Car=>1]]` ? That will be fine for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array:3 [▼
  Bus => "1"
  Bus => "1"
  Car => "1"
]
```

It's impossible, because the keys must unique

you can make it to

```
["Bus", "Bus", "Car"]
```

or

```
["Bus" => 2, "Car" => 1]
```

---

Answer to updated question

You can do like this:

```
$array = [
            "id" => 13,
            "agent_id" => 1,
            "reserved_by" => 1,
            "vehicle_type" => array("Bus", "Car"),
            "no_of_vehicle" => array("2", "1"),
            "created_at" => "2017-06-13 05:46:49",
            "updated_at" => "2017-06-13 05:46:49",
        ];

        $result = [];

        foreach ($array["vehicle_type"] as $key => $vehicle) {
            $num = intval($array["no_of_vehicle"][$key]);
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $num; $i++) {
                $result[] = array($vehicle => "1");
            }
        }
```

the `$result` will be:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "Bus" => "1"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "Bus" => "1"
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    "Car" => "1"
  ]
]
```

Comment: sorry, now i've added the solutions @LawrenceCherone

Answer (score 0):

I would create an array like that :

```
array[
  {
    vehicle_type => 'Bus',
    no_of_vehicle => 2,
  },
  {
    vehicle_type => 'Car',
    no_of_vehicle => 1,
  }
]
```

or

```
array['Bus_1', 'Bus_2', 'Car_1']
```

Comment: Or use answer of @brobrobrobrobro :-)